# Forwarding Azure logs to ELK

Tags: azure, elastic-stack, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

We have an application running on Azure. We use Application Insights to monitor the cloud solution. To monitor the application itself we started playing with the log analytics but it seemed that it was almost impossible to get custom logs decently parsed by log analytics.
Therefore we are looking into using an ELK instance.
However, I cannot find the right documentation on how to set this up.
Is anyone familiar with something like that to point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: Can you tell me more about the problems you have with parsing the custom logs? I know that log analytics is very powerful so maybe we can help with the parsing issues.

Comment: I followed the steps as described in the Azure Log Analytics manual. Via Log Analytics, I went to Advanced Settings > Data > Custom Logs. There I added the log collection using Windows path D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Function\xxxx\*.log. Then I went to Application Insights but I cannot search for the logs I previously added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite generic so I only have this as a pointer for log parsing:

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

Might be just what you need. If it's not sufficient, browse through the other logstash filters.